# How can I get access to the DLC cars?

Tags: grid-2

As part of pre-ordering Grid 2 on Steam, I got the following day one DLC packs;

- Headstart Pack
- McLaren Racing Pack
- GTR Racing Pack

With these DLCs I'm supposed to get immediate access to a variety of new cars, such as the Mercedes-Benz SLR McLaren 722 GT and McLaren MP4-12C GT3 however all of the races at the beginning of the game are locking me in to using a Ford Mustang Mach 1 Twister Special.

Do I have to unlock these cars somehow or am I missing something that is resulting in me being limited to only using this car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These cars are just in your garage. However the races are limited to a certain tier of car, so you will only be able to use some cars for some races.

When you view the race, you will notice the logo of the allowed cars on the splash screen. This logo matches up to the ones in your garage.

To view your current cars, you can, from the main menu select 'My Vehicles' and then browse right across the categories. The cars you have available will cause the logo in that category to highlight. The SLR is in the highest tier alongside the McLaren.